# ifnull() function in where clause MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables.

```
**Employee**
EmpId NOT NULL (PK)
Name NOT NULL
OrgID NULL (FK)

**Organisation**
OrgID NOT NULL (PK)
OrgName NOT NULL
```

I want to get Name,OrgName with one select statement.
but condition is OrgID can be null in Employee table. So many records without OrgID and records with OrgID too.

How can get all data by passing EmpId with one sql statement?

Thanks.

Comment: You mean you want to show all Employees's names, including those that are not related to an Organization (their Employee.OrdId is NULL?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
select e.name, o.OrgName 
from Employee e
left join Organisation o on o.OrgID = e.OrgID
where e.EmpId = ?;
```

OrgName will be `null` in the result rows if the FK is null.

Answer (score 1):

Use `LEFT JOIN` ie

```
SELECT
  e.Name,
  O.OrgName
FROM Employee e
LEFT JOIN Organisation O ON(O.OrgID = e.OrgID)
WHERE EmpId = x
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine:

```
SELECT 
  e.Name
  , o.OrgName 
FROM Employee AS e 
LEFT JOIN Organisation AS o ON e.OrgID=o.OrgID 
WHERE e.EmpId = ?;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Employee 
LEFT JOIN Organisation ON 
    Employee.OrgID == Organisation.OrgID 
WHERE 
    EmpId = ?;
```

[This link will give you more details](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlleftjoin.php)

EDIT: Forgot to include WHERE clause

Comment: It should be **`=`**, not `==`.